# Why are there Braintree classes and methods missing from Xarmain jar binding project?

Tags: c#, android, jar, xamarin, braintree

I am attempting to bind Braintree's client sdk ([braintree-api 1.6.4](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22braintree-api%22)) to a Xamarin jar bindings project.

So far, I've added the jar file to a bindings project. I've altered the [Metadata.xml](https://github.com/twolf611/Xamarin-Braintree.Android-Bindings/blob/master/Transforms/Metadata.xml) with several configurations in order to get the project to compile.

When I added the project as a reference to a Xamarin.Android project, several methods and classes were missing. In particular, the Braintree, BraintreeApi, and AndroidPay classes were missing. In order to force the bindings project to show the Braintree class, I added an `<add-node>` tag to the [Metadata.xml](https://github.com/twolf611/Xamarin-Braintree.Android-Bindings/blob/master/Transforms/Metadata.xml):

```
<add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.braintreepayments.api']">
      <class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" extends="java.lang.Object" 
           extends-generic-aware="java.lang.Object" final="false" name="Braintree" 
           static="false" visibility="public">
     </class>
</add-node>
```

The Braintree class is now available in the Xamarin.Android project; unfortunately, when I attempt to instantiate the class I am unable to access any of the methods.

When I add the jar file to a regular java project, I am able to see all the classes and methods (so I am pretty sure the jar is not corrupted or incomplete).

This is my first time attempting a Xamarin jar bindings project, and also working with Braintree (I'm unfamiliar with both). Any direction, recommendations, or [pull requests](https://github.com/twolf611/Xamarin-Braintree.Android-Bindings) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: have you carefully reviewed the build output of the binding project to verify that there aren't any applicable messages or warnings?

Comment: @Jason: Using the Metadata.xml, I am able to remove all the errors; however, there are a large amount of warnings that I have not been able to resolve. Such as: `Warning J2XA006: missing class error was raised while reflecting com.braintreepayments.api.AndroidPay : com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions$HasOptions (J2XA006) (BrainTree)` `Warning J2XA006: missing class error was raised while reflecting com.braintreepayments.api.Braintree : com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters (J2XA006) (BrainTree)`

Comment: What is the build action of the jar file(s)? Only jars with the build action of "Input Jar" will generate their classes.

Comment: `BraintreeApi` contains a few dependencies that are resolved using maven (visible in the [pom file](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.braintreepayments.api%7Cbraintree-api%7C1.6.4%7Cjar)). You may want to try the full jar that contains these dependencies.